# Displaying some contents with jquery in onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to display a video with codeignier as a result of an image click.
Iam displaying images with the help of a forloop.

```
 <div class="inner active">
<img src="imagepath" alt="" class="img-thumbnail" width="320" height="240" onclick="loadvideo('<?php echo $cam->ip;?>')" />
</div>
```

And i have got a video div which is hidden

```
<div class="video" style="display: none;">
      <video  id="v1" width="320" height="240" controls="controls">

      </video>
    </div>
```

With an ajax call creating the video and display in the view. Wen i click on the first image, i need to replace the image with video. the other image must remain unchanged. This is what iam trying to do. But now my both images are changing and showing the video. What should i do to display one video while the other image remain unchanged. My script is as follows

```
  success: function(data){
               $('.inner').hide();
               $('.video').show();
               $('#loadingmessage').hide();
               $("#v1").html('<source src='+data.video+' type="video/mp4 "></source>' );
```

Comment: What is the error/issue?

Comment: both images are changing. and displaying the video. actually i have a list of images. wen i click on the first image, all the other images are replaced with a video

Comment: May be your class or id is conflict .. check your html .. because your html is in loop right?

Comment: yes your class name remain same in loop that is why replace all over.

Comment: if i give an id too, it will be in the same loop, no?

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided entire code. 
As per your query you have not created an dynamic id. used the class that means it is not unique.

Try to create an ID for each object dynamically. And use that dynamic Id to use show hide functionality.  eg:

```
inner_vid0001, inner_vid0002, inner_vid0003

video_show0001, video_show0002, video_show0003
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether I understood your problem correctly, Are you expecting something like this ?
When you click on any of the image it will replace by the underlying video. 
This is a very basic code/idea, you can very easily improve this code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.item').click(function() {
    $(this).find('img').attr('style', 'display:none');
    $(this).find('.hide').removeClass('hide').addClass('show');
  });

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">

  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active">
      </li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/la.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:100%;">

        <div class="hide" id="Vid1">
          <video id="v1" width="320" height="240" controls="controls" src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4">
          </video>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/chicago.jpg" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">

        <div class="hide" id="Vid2">
          <video id="v2" width="320" height="240" controls="controls"></video>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/ny.jpg" alt="New york" style="width:100%;">

        <div class="hide" id="Vid3">
          <video id="v3" width="320" height="240" controls="controls"></video>
        </div>


      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way to change the video src on the fly.

You need to test this on Firefox, but it should work. There has been some issues with the `load()` function.

```
success: function(data){
     $('.inner').hide();
     $('.video').show();
     $('#loadingmessage').hide();
     $("#v1").src = data.video;
     $("#v1").load();
```

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you have the elements :

```
<div>
 <img id="1" src="blabla.jpg">
 <img id="2" src="blabla2.jpg">
</div>
```

You want to replace one image with video and so on, right ?
You must call the id of that images to replace with one video. Like this :

```
$('#1').click(function(e){
  e.eventPreventDefault();
  $(this).replaceWith('<div class="video" style="display: none;">
      <video  id="v1" width="320" height="240" controls="controls">

      </video>
    </div>');
});
```

Or you can loop that images with each() function

```
$('img').each(function(i,e){
  $(this).replaceWith($('<div class="video" style="display: none;">
      <video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">

      </video>
    </div>').click(function(e){
  //Call ajax
  }));
  });
```

And in ajax, insert source tag :

```
success: function(data){
               $("#v1").html('<source src='+data.video+' type="video/mp4 "></source>' );
```